# Video stops after a few loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Video stops after a few loop, before I am updated Chrome browser this bug did not exist.

```
var Video = document.getElementById('video');
$('#video').hide();
if (typeof Video.loop == 'boolean') { 
    Video.loop = true;
} else { 
    Video.bind('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        console.log("ended");
    }, false);
}
```

If I remove this code and run this :

```
Video.bind('ended', function() {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
            console.log("ended");
        }, false);
```

I can see 15 times "ended" in my js console, after nothing happen and video stops.
Chrome version 27.0.1453.116 m on Windows 7 Ultimate

Edited:
This issue appear only with .mp4 for .ogg autoloop works correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having an issue binding the ended event to the video element because you call `$('#video').hide();` first. I know this affects click events, so it might also be affecting video player events.

Try putting the hide call underneath your if statement:

```
var Video = document.getElementById('video');
if (typeof Video.loop == 'boolean') { 
    Video.loop = true;
} else { 
    Video.bind('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        console.log("ended");
    }, false);
}
$('#video').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I think the latest Chrome update causes this issue but I don't know why and how to find workaround.

Comment: Might be related to this recent bug in Chromium (maybe you should add a comment to the thread to help them reproduce): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=255369